# SimpleXML object array only return the first value in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

### Question summary

Why does SimpleXML object array only return the first value, and not all array elements.

---

### Question Explanation

**XML structure (simplified)**

```
<states>
    <state>
        <name>California</name>
        <cities>
            <city>
                <name>LosAngeles</name>
            </city>
            <city>
                <name>SanFrancisco</name>
            </city>
        </cities>
    </state>
    <state>
        <name>Nevada</name>
        <cities>
            <city>
                <name>LasVegas</name>
            </city>
        </cities>
    </state>
</states>
```

**Method (simplified)**

I have `getCityList` method in my `City` class:

```
public function getCityList( $givenState = false ){
    $records = array();
    $states = $this->states->state;

    [var_dump( $states->asXML() )]
    [var_dump( $states[0]->asXML() )]
    [var_dump( $states[1]->asXML() )]

    foreach( $states as $state ){
        if( empty( $givenState ) || ( $state->name == $givenState ) ){
            $cities = $state->cities->city;
            foreach( $cities as $city ){
                $records[ trim( $state->name ) ][] = trim( $city->name );   
            }
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }
    return $records;
}
```

for both `$givenState = 'California'` and `$givenState = 'Nevada'`, `var_dump( $states->asXML() )` gives:

```
<state>
    <name>California</name>
    <cities>
        <city>
            <name>LosAngeles</name>
        </city>
        <city>
            <name>SanFrancisco</name>
        </city>
    </cities>
</state>
```

while `var_dump( $states[0]->asXML() )` gives:

```
<state>
    <name>California</name>
    <cities>
        <city>
            <name>LosAngeles</name>
        </city>
        <city>
            <name>SanFrancisco</name>
        </city>
    </cities>
</state>
```

and `var_dump( $states[1]->asXML() )` gives:

```
<state>
    <name>Nevada</name>
    <cities>
        <city>
            <name>LasVegas</name>
        </city>
    </cities>
</state>
```

The `getCityList` method returns correct result on `$givenState = 'California'` and `false` on `$givenState = 'Nevada'`.

Why this array has this behavior?

How can I get it to work so that `Nevada` results are also returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `return false;` after first mismatch in `if` in your  `foreach( $states as $state )` that if why you are getting false for second check, you need to remove `return false` and let loop check all items and return `$records` or `false` at the end outside loop, like this

```
....
if( empty($givenState){
    return false;
}

foreach( $states as $state ){
    if( $state->name == $givenState ){
        $cities = $state->cities->city;
        foreach( $cities as $city ){
            $records[ trim( $state->name ) ][] = trim( $city->name );   
        }
    }
}

return count($records) ? $records:false;
```

also i moved `empty($givenState)` above loop